# How to keep track of and save pattern in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am having the following code.

```
text = "#QUESTION Hello, how are you? #ANSWER I am fine."
pattern = re.compile('#QUESTION((.|\s|$)[^#]+)')
matches = pattern.findall(text)
```

I want to extract from the text variable the part that says `#QUESTION Hello, how are you?` However, when I apply the regular expression under pattern, I only obtain `Hello, how are you?` I would also like to include the `#QUESTION` tag, so that it says `#QUESTION Hello, how are you?` How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just alter your current expression to include "#Question" in the group.

```
#includes parentheses around the #QUESTION and the rest of the expression)
pattern = re.compile('(#QUESTION(?:(?:.|\s|$)[^#]+))')
```

`(?: expression)` indicates a grouping that you don't want to keep track of. In other words, for the purpose of the expression those characters all mean something together, but you don't want to separately keep track of it.